# Best practive for JUnit package naming?

Tags: java, junit

I was trying to find some best practice for naming Java package for testing. I would be thinking something along:

Tests on:

```
com.example.MyClass
```

should be in:

```
com.example.test.MyClassTest
```

Comment: (While this *is* a matter of opinion to some extent, I don't think it's arbitrary - hence my answer instead of close vote. That in itself was a judgement call though...)

Comment: The idea was not to start a troll debate, but to investigate what developers are doing.

Answer (score 7):

Typically I put the test classes in the *same* package, but under a different source root. Aside from anything else, this allows you to test members (and indeed classes) which have default visibility. Sometimes I'll even make methods which would otherwise be private, package-level to make testing easier, knowing that it will only have limited impact. This very much depends on the context in which you're developing though. (Most of my code is written in a trusted environment; I want to limit access for elegance, but I'm not worried that anyone will actively try to use a method they shouldn't. And I use an annotation to indicate the intention.)

You definitely want an easy way of separating out your test classes from your production classes, both for deployment purposes and to let you concentrate on "just the prod code" when appropriate. But I don't see any disadvantage in using the same package declaration for both tests and production code.

Comment: Wrote my answer because I thought yours was a little short. After the edit it's a clear +1 ;-)

Comment: The only risk I see is overwriting of files... no?

Comment: @jgp: Why would files be overwritten? Which files in particular are you worried about? You'd still give the test classes different names to the production classes...

Comment: Sure, but let's imagine I am paranoid and i have some configuration files, properties, etc. in the same package...

This all comes from a project i am on, where, when the tests are in the project, run fails, if you get rid of the tests, it works... Hence getting slightly paranoid and looking for good best practice

Comment: @jgp: Well I've been using this practice for years and not had a problem.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best options is putting the tests in another source folder. This way you can easily seperate the acctual source from the tests, e.g. when building a release. Take a look at Mavens [default directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). A propper IDE should be able to handle different source folders even without Maven.

As for the package: If you have two different source folders, you can have the test classes in the same package. This has several advantages like beeing able to access package protected members from your test or using nice plugins like [MoreUnit](http://moreunit.sourceforge.net/).